# Selected Row Doesn't delete

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am a newbie in using asp.net, I have a problem with the GridView: after I selected the value that I should void, it should be deleted on the GridView.

I use this code `dtable.Rows.RemoveAt(i)` but it's not working. Do you have any idea about this??? thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 2):

are you rebinding Gridview again after delete? Do you want to delete it from datatabase or only client side? Try to add following code

```
Gridview1.DataSource = dttable;
Gridview1.DataBind();
```

After your

```
dtable.Rows.RemoveAt(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to rebind the GridView.

```
GridView1.DataBind()
```

Comment: The gridview becomes empty :(

Comment: In that case, as rs. said, also re set the DataSource.